# How to rig a switch to swap a bone's parents?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, drivers, parent

I'm trying to figure out how to use Child of constraints to swap a bone's parents when pulling a bone switch. This is a simple enough task when done manually, as shown below:

[image]

But I run into problems when trying to set up the drivers to have the switch swap them. Setting up the constraint for Parent 1 is easy:

[image]

This makes it so that the when pulled, the Switch bone controls the influence of the Child of_1 constraint from 0-1 when moved in the positive Y direction. But to pull off what I want done, I need the Child of_2 constraint to start at 1 influence, and move to 0 when the switch is moved. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Python expression** to do that :

Let's say the switch bone change the influence when its Y location is more or less than zero.

Add a variable to the driver which is based on this location, then use its value in a scripted expression, here "var > 0" which returns the value "True" (equal to 1) if var is positive and returns "False" (equal to 0) if var is negative.

[image]

For the second driver, do the same, but with an expression "var <= 0" to have the opposite values in return.
You can also choose to say "var < 0" if you want that none of the parent influences the child when exactly 0.

[image]

In result :

[image]

Note : when you validate something in the second driver, Blender switch back the selection to the first driver... a little bug maybe. So beware at which one is selected in the drivers panel, all the time.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!